# How can we declare Interface with Internal Keyword

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

Interface is a contract between client and server and it is necessary for a server to define or implement methods declared in interface. This is definition of internal and I believe that it  means Interface should be public only, but while creating Interface when I use internal keyword before interface it works fine and doesn't give me any compile time error, but I didn't understand why.

Edit : Even if we can declare interface as internal it is necessary for a class method implementing interface member to be public. Why this?

Comment: C# `interface`s have nothing to do with clients or servers.  An `interface` is a type.

Comment: so what you mean is that interface is not a contract between client and server ?

Comment: It depends on how you define "interface", "client", "server", and "contract" ;-)

Comment: @SLaks, there is arcane usage of "client and server" which used in exact meaning as in the post - OLE/COM objects are called this way... But 99.9% you right that is not meaning Ashish puts in those words...

Comment: I think that actual use of interface is that if client uses Interface variable at its end than it is 100% sure that it can use whatever methods declared in interface and even if there are changes in server class functionality can't break

Comment: @AshishKhandelwal: That is one use of an interface, except not with clients and servers.  (If the server changes the interface, the client will be messed up)

Comment: If interface is only promise of certain methods or properties will be implemented than why member methods implementing interfaces we always need to keep as public and not even internal

Comment: In general questions "why XXXX done this way in .Net Framework" (or any other product) are not answerable by community - there could be real reasons or it just happen to be so i.e. due some unrelated technical reasons. You may be able to find answer on CLR blogs or books... Side note: You can explicitly implement interface and as result method will not be public (but still callable via casting to the interface).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The internal keyword means that the class or interface can only be used by other classes within the same assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(VS.80).aspx

An interface is not necessarily a contract between two clients or servers, but rather it's a promise that an object will implement certain methods or properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: 'Interface is a promise of ...' i like this, mind if i borrow the phrase? +1 btw